# Vue modal component using in parent component

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm building simple modal component with Vue. I want to use this component in a parent components and to be able to toggle it from the parent.

This is my code now of the modal component:

```js
<script>
export default {
 name: 'Modal',
 data() {
  return {
   modalOpen: true,
  }
 },
 methods: {
  modalToggle() {
   this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
 <div v-if="modalOpen" class="modal">
  <div class="body">
   body
  </div>
  <div class="btn_cancel" @click="modalToggle">
   <i class="icon icon-cancel" />
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

I use the **v-if** to toggle the rendering and it works with the button i created inside my modal component.

However my problem is: I don't know how to toggle it with simple button from parent component. I don't know how to access the modalOpen data from the modal component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's try to do it right. I propose to make a full-fledged component and control the opening and closing of a modal window using the v-model in parent components or in other includes.

1) We need declare prop - "value" in "props" for child component.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Modal',
    props: ["value"],
    data() {
        return {
            modalOpen: true,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        modalToggle() {
            this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

2) Replace your "modalToggle" that:

```
modalToggle() {
  this.$emit('input', !this.value);
}
```

3) In parent components or other includes declare "modal=false" var and use on component v-model="modal" and any control buttons for modal var.

**summary**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="value" class="modal">
        <div class="body">
            body
        </div>
        <div class="btn_cancel" @click="modalToggle">
            <i class="icon icon-cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: ["value"],
  methods: {
    modalToggle() {
      this.$emit("input", !this.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Example:**

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '<div v-if="value" class="modal"><div class="body">modal body</div><div class="btn_cancel" @click="modalToggle">close modal<i class="icon icon-cancel" /></div></div>',
  props: ["value"],
 methods: {
  modalToggle() {
      this.$emit('input', !this.value);
  }
 }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:() =>({
  modal: false
  }),
  methods: {
  openModal() {
  this.modal = !this.modal;
  }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="openModal">Btn modal</div>
  
  <modal v-model="modal"></modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Now it works as desired. I have one side question.
What's a proper way to open the modal after short delay ? Is using a function like setInterval() or something similar ?

Comment: Depending on the purpose. What is your purpose with setInterval()?

Comment: I want after my landing page loads, after short delay (5sec for example)  my modal component to pop up, I also want to pop up once and not on every page reloading

Comment: I think you can use setTimeout (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instand of setInterval for one launch. After it you needs store state, you can use localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Also you can use hook created() on page and detect state after reload page.

Answer (score 1):

With your current implementation I would suggest you to use refs
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

So in your parent component add `ref="child"` to modal (child) component and then open your modal by calling `this.$refs.child.modalToggle()`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use an "activator" slot
2. You can use ref="xxx" on the child and access it from the parent